# SQL Query help, how to find cities with international flights?

Tags: sql

So I was given a database with two Tables, one being `Airport` and `Flights`.

```
Airport 
(City ,Nation)

Flights
(FlightID, DepartureCity,ArrivalCity)
```

I am supposed to write a query that will list cities with international flight departures, but I can't figure out the proper syntax.

I know I need to have my clause being `DepartureCity (Nation) != ArrivalCity(Nation)`, but how would I write this in SQL?

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN` the tables together.  Twice.

Comment: There is a solution here for you.  I see you're new so first of all, welcome to Stackoverflow.  Also, don't forget to 'Accept' an answer if it works for you.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select distinct f.DepartureCity
    from Flights f
    inner join Airport a1 on a1.City = f.DepartureCity
    inner join Airport a2 on a2.City = f.ArrivalCity
    where a1.Nation <> a2.Nation
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! I think this helps! One thing though, I haven't used or learned about DISTINCT yet, can you explain what it does?

Comment: Your very welcome @CPPNoob - In that case, please don't forget to 'Accept' this as the answer.  Thanks.

Comment: @CPPNoob  - As for DISTINCT - Without it, this query would return rows listing the DepartureCity once for every international flight leaving that city (since we are reading from the Flights table).  The DISTINCT says "only show each DepartureCity one time".

Comment: @CPPNoob - You could remove the DISTINCT and see for yourself.  Try changing the first line to   " select * "   and you will see the full result set.